# onclick listener not working on ImageButton inside CollapsingToolbarLayout android

Tags: android

[onclick function on edit image button not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdETx.png)[In coordinatorLayout....Im inserting the image button to right of  collapsingToolbar title ,setOnClickListener not working on that image button.... You can find the code and images below. Any help is appreciated[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2gZg.png)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bgheader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/nature"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/txt_group_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/edit"
                android:onClick="dd"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relative1"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

```
private View mGroupName;
   mGroupName = (View) findViewById(R.id.txt_group_name);
   mGroupName.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.txt_group_name: {
                final EditText txtUrl = new EditText(GroupInformationActivity.this);
                txtUrl.setText(group.getName());
                new AlertDialog.Builder(GroupInformationActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("New name for the group")
                        .setView(txtUrl)
                        .setPositiveButton("Change", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                String name = txtUrl.getText().toString();
                                if (!group.getName().equals(name)) {
                                    collapsingToolbar.setTitle(name);
                                    new UpdateGroupTask().execute();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
.......
```

Comment: Show code where setting listener for ImageButton

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK , here is the code..

Comment: you just forgot to add `break` at the end of you case.

Comment: @vrundpurohit, I have completed in the actual file. The code runs without error. I just didn't put the while thing here.

Comment: @DurveshMirashe: try `ImageButton  mGroupName = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.txt_group_name);`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: i tried that .bt it doesn't work....

Comment: I've same problem. Did you find the solution

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late but I was having the same issue and the reason ended up being the `Toolbar` was consuming the click event so it wasn't getting passed down to the `ImageButton` in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I ended up just moving the `ImageButton` inside the `Toolbar` and then everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can create new CustomerToolbar extends Toolbar,and make CustomerToolbar method:
onTouchEvent and onInterceptTouchEvent return false

in my case:

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (alpha >= 1) {
            return false
        } else {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
        }
    }

   

    override fun onTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        if (alpha >= 1) {
            return false
        } else {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at my Toolbar code:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar
            ) findViewById(R.id.account_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);  

    btnEdit = toolbar.findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
    btnEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

when your button is inside toolbar layout, you have to initialise toolbar first and then with reference of toolbar you can access all components inside it and perform operations.

Comment: not in toolbar it mean about collabsing toolbar so i -1